# My script is not working and I have no idea why

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have a script that is attached to a block that changes the scene when the player steps into it. It was working fine before it referenced another script I made to add a fade effect between scene. I keep getting errors that say I should put random semi colons in the Change function. However the script seems fine to me. Can any one tell me what I've done wrong?

```
var inArea = false;
var LevelToGo = "";

function Update () {
    if (inArea == true) {
        MyCoroutine();
    }
}

function OnTriggerEnter2D(other: Collider2D)
{
    Debug.Log("OnTriggerEnter");
    if(other.tag == "Player")
    {
        inArea = true;
    }
}

function OnTriggerExit2D(other: Collider2D)
{
    if(other.tag == "Player")
    {
        inArea = false;
    }
}

function Change(){
    yield WaitForSeconds (0.5);
    float fadeTime = GameObject.Find("_GM").GetComponent<Fading>().BeginFade(1);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(fadeTime);
    Application.LoadLevel (LevelToGo);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you are using javascript but i think this line

```
yield return new WaitForSeconds(fadeTime);
```

is C#. this might confuse the compiler

try

```
yield WaitForSeconds(fadeTime);
```

Comment: It got rid of one error but there's 4 more. Looking at it I think the line that states the float, fadeTime, is in c# also. How would i re-write it in java-script?

Comment: I just re-wrote the scrip in c# instead. However i get an error when I open the Change void. I'm guessing voids can't have yield commands. What do I use instead of void?

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems is that you are using yield outside of a coroutine, and a yield can only be issued inside a coroutine.

To make it simple, you should make the return type "**IEnumerator**" and then call the coroutine with "StartCoroutine(Change());". For more information you could checkout the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/es/2021.1/Manual/Coroutines.html).